# Why was my reply deleted?

Tags: discussion

@fossfreedom: I have replied in this topic:
[How to install Ubuntu on a IBM R31 Thinkpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368258/ubuntu-installation-help-for-an-ibm-r31-thinkpad/409752#409752)

I thought I posted valuable, additional information to a reply from Steeldriver.
However, my post/reply was deleted.

If it was because it looked like hyjacking someone else's post, I apologize for that. This was not what I meant to do.

I posted my message because I think it contains more information which may help to solve the Original question from David Taylor.

(Steeldriver wrote about the boot options on a similar thinkpad x30, which has boot from usb support, the thinkpad r31 seems to have fewer options in the bios / boot menu)

So I believe my post was deleted for the wrong reasons and my post was intended to help to solve the Original issue (which I am having too)

Comment: Would you please post nick of moderator who delete it? My post got deleted recently in another thread too.

Comment: nick of moderator is fossfreedom. I've contacted him via his blog and he advised me to post ask a question about it here with a link to the Original topic.

Comment: It's not that moderator who deleted my post. But those deletions unhearten enthusiasts. I hope it's not policy of askubuntu. I like here.

Comment: ok. thanks, I missed that. If it's not migrated by a moderator, I will post it there.

Comment: @kenn read foss answer. Anything that you post that is not an answer could and will be deleted by the community. Please, check the help page http://askubuntu.com/help/deleted-answers

Answer (score 9):

For this case, your answer was really a question.  This is why it was deleted - and indeed, I posted a link pointing you in that direction.

Whilst your question may have a bearing on the original posters (OP) question - in these situations, it is best to create your own question that you can actively own.

The community themselves will decide if your question is different enough to warrant duplication against the original.  One way to guard against closure is to state that the answers in the linked question have not helped.  Provide details within your question of what you have tried, errors seen etc for each of the answers you've tried.

You can maintain your own question by editing whenever comments are made seeking further clarification.

That is how this site works best - creating your own question and editing it until you have an answer you like, can accept - and upvote.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your explanation. It is clear although I do not understand why it is this way, but that's something else.